# Marmalade: error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'python.lib

Tags: windows-phone-8, linker-errors, marmalade

I'm trying to build Marmalade project for Windows Phone 8 in Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 but receive following error:

```
error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'python.lib'
```

Seems that it happens because of wrong path to project's additional library directories. Currently it's `c:\users\*user_name_omitted*\appdata\roaming\marmalade\packages\6.3.0\python_2.6.4\lib\wp8\x86`

But in fact there is no `wp8` folder. As I understand this foulder should be created automatically...

I have Marmalade evaluation license.

How can i get rid ot this error?

Comment: packages gets downloaded automatically whenever there's an update and you open a mkb. Try to move all the packages to some other folder and open some test mkb.

Comment: @Creator it doesn't help

Comment: @Creator do you have license, which covers wp8? If yes, maybe you can upload somewhere contents of your "wp8" folder?

Comment: My packages/6.3.0 folder is empty too, but marmalade is running fine here, so I guess that's not the source of issues you are having.
 And I've Indie license.

Comment: @Creator just thought that it's licensing problem, but seems that I was wrong

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:

I've not got a working version to hand, but the bundled version of python with marmalade is (IIRC) 2.5.x, so the reference to 2.6.4 looks odd. I wonder if when you ran s3eConfig it was running a different version and got confused? More as like it should have downloaded some extra stuff and has not.

It might be worth uninstalling marmalade and then re-installing. There are reports of people not having a full installation following the install.

Comment: Reinstall of Marmalade doesn't help and seems that 2.6.4 is correct version